# setting parameters from working curl to gatling parameteres

Tags: scala, curl, gatling

I have the following working curl:

```
curl --request POST   --url 'https://xxx/connect/token'   --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'   --data grant_type=client_credentials   --data 'client_id=xxx'   --data client_secret=xxx   --data audience=xxx/kj_api
```

But reproducing in Gatling(scala) is not working like this:

```
package magnus

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class OAuthSimulation extends Simulation {

val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("https://xxx.no")
    .inferHtmlResources()
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip,deflate")
    .contentTypeHeader("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .userAgentHeader("Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)")

val headers_0 = Map("Authorization" -> "Bearer xxx")

val scn = scenario("tokenSimulation")

    .exec(http("request_token")
        .post("/connect/token")
        .headers(headers_0))

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

How can I set the parameters from the working curl to my Gatling script?

Thanks,
Magnus

Answer (score 0):

Hi Magnus it looks like you would need to use a URL that includes the QUERY PARAMS.

So something like 'https://xxx/connect/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxx' ... etc

Take a look at https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request/#query-parameters for more information

Comment: get the same error here: {"error":"invalid_client"}

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.formParam("key", "value")`

```
  .exec(http("request_token")
            .post("/connect/token")
            .headers(headers_0))
            .formParam("audience", "xxx/kj_api")
            .formParam("client_id", "xxx")
            .formParam("client_secret", "xxx")
            .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")
```

Comment: Tried it but get the response: HTTP response:
status=
400 Bad Request
headers= 
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server: Kestrel
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2020 13:04:32 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63113852
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: Keep-Alive
transfer-encoding: chunked
content-encoding: gzip

body=
{"error":"invalid_client"}
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<